# POWERBI - Date format to show as 2023-01 on x-axis instead of 2023-Jan // Must be date not extracted 'Whole#' or 'Text' Due to dynamic calculation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Date - display axis as 2023-01 , 2023-02 and so on instead of 2023 January
Hi I have DAX calculation set up for dynamic date calculation such as YOY, MOM changes.

I spent 6 hours looking for answers yet i cannot find anything that resolved my isssue. If i don't need calculations, i can simply extract, YYYY, MM from the date column as 'whole#' or 'text' and do grouping, charting easy. However, for certain charts, tables I need to use date functions to dynamically calculate stuff, in this case I need to use 'Date- Hierarchy' as the X-AXIS. The issue is, it displays 2023-Jan, 2023-Feb and so on. I must show this as 2023-1, 2023-2, 2021-2 and so on, as they MM is intended to represent PERIOD. Any tips? I looked youtube, chatgpt, whatever no conclusive answer yet. Why Microsoft doens't give us option to display like in excel, you can show as Jan-2023, 2023-Jan, 2023-1 and so on. BI i changed to custom format, and the table show as 2023-01 but as soon as i apply on my chart, it changes to 2023-January.

HELP! If not, i might need to rework huge dataset into POWERQUERY and use Excel, which i hate to do since computation is slower and data cleaning will take a while. Also, setting up PIVOT will take time and not dynamic.

1. Extract yyyy-mm as whole number but DAX date calculations such as MOM % changes and YOY% changes gets messed up since no longer they are date
2. Change format to YYYY-MM, but this only changes the table but as soon as i display on the x-axis it changes to 2023-Jan and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to google for a so-called Date or Calendar table, where you can add/include different components or “layouts” of a date in different columns (e.g. yyyy-mm)

Use that table as date reference to define your customized date hierarchy.

Comment: I already have calendar table setup, it's not about matching period and months, it's about displaying X-AXIS as 2023-01 instead of 2023-Jan.    For some non-calculating x-axis i already use PERIOD + YEAR as trend lines but for YOY or MOM calculations dynamic calculation i cannot.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. Using calendar table enables you to calculate a measure for YoY and MoM with one column (e.g. the full date)  while using other columns (yyyy, yyyy-mm, etc.) to build up the date hierarchy for the visual, at the same time.